# Что означает legacy код?

Tags: java, терминология

Что означает 'legacy' код в терминах языка программирования java?
Есть ли такое понятие 'legacy' и что оно означает?
К примеру есть  тег:@deprecated - он конкретно означает то-то  и то в контексте программирования на java.
Мне не совсем понятно legacy код - это гарантия без срока давности?

PS. Вопрос возник в связи с тем, что работодатели пишут в требованиях: Опыт работы с legacy кодом? Есть ли четкое внятное определение legacy кода?
Вопрос частично решился благодаря ответам из Wiki и книге: Майкл Физерс - "Эффективная работа с унаследованным кодом"